# Forge viewer - How to link restored markups with their label text written on it while camera change event

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

In my markup, I add a label on it using (x,y) co-ordinates using "markup.markups[0].getClientPosition". This works, but if I change camera mode or rotate it will lose it place, so am wondering how I can put it back to the new position as per the new markup position?
I understand I have to add event listener for "CAMERA_CHANGE_EVENT", but how I should relate the label with its corresponding svg markup, what if there are more than one markups?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest to use the 3d markup extension to make things easier - it supports navigation right out of the box

Follow here to get started: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/3d-markup-icons-and-info-card

Or SVG markups work well as well: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/create-pushpin-markup-svg

Comment: from below pushpin example, I tried it but it give me error for snap function, how to fix snap function?

Comment: why bother trying the samples in an answer that you downvoted at all?